# imagecreatefromjpeg crashing without error message

Tags: php, file-upload

So I'm creating thumbnail and uploading some image files to webserver.
My code is working with `png` but I have no idea why it's crashing with `jpeg/jpg`.

#### FrontEnd

```
<form method="POST" action="ajax.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="uploadImage[]" id="file_input"> 
   <input type="file" name="uploadImage[]" id="file_input1"> 
   <input type="file" name="uploadImage[]" id="file_input2"> 
   <input type="submit" name="sendBtn" value="Click me">
</form>
```

#### Ajax.php

```
$file_ary = reArrayFiles($_FILES['uploadImage']); //Reorder array
foreach ($file_ary as $file) {
   if(file_exists($file['tmp_name'])) {
      $parts = pathinfo($name);
      $ext = $parts['extension'];
      if($ext == 'png') {
         $imageSource = imagecreatefrompng($image);//Works
      }
      else if($ext == 'jpeg' || $ext == 'jpg') {
         $imageSource = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);//Crashes!!
      }
   }
}
```

The only error I get:
`HTTP 500 - Server is unable to handle this request`

I tested several jpg files with different resolutions and sizes. I Can't figure out the problem neither a way to find the problem.

Comment: Have you got PHP errors turned on? `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Also check you `phpinfo();` for JPG support enabled (https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZwAR.png)

Comment: @BrettGregson I added that to the initial part of my ajax.php but I got the same result. A crashed page with the message I mentioned above. Also, I forgot to mention... Damnn. I check your image link and my `phpinfo()` output is actually different. I have no jpeg info there. Guess that is the problem.

Comment: @BrettGregson Couldn't find a way to fix it. Would you have a clue? (I'm running php 5.3)

Comment: Sure. Are you using something like MAMP/WAMP etc. or is this on a server?

Comment: @BrettGregsonIts running on our server. All I could find was "ways to `recompile` php". NO way to "Just add the module support for jpeg" or something like that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198594/discussion-between-brett-gregson-and-playhardgopro).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. When I

`echo phpinfo()`

I found out that I didn't have **JPEG SUPPORT**.

[image]
I had to recompile the php with the right support of GD lib.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding strtostrtolower($ext) before your if statements.

Comment: That's not the problem. It is entering the 'if` statement, but is crashing.